# unable to get key_type from a map

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote this piece of code in order to check if a `std::map` contains a specific key:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args >
inline bool contains(const std::map<Args...>& map, const T& value) noexcept
{
  static_assert(std::is_constructible_v< decltype(map)::key_type , T >);

  return map.find(value) != std::end(map);
}
```

I have the following error:

> error: `key_type` is not a member of `const std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Query>&`

What is the problem with `decltype(map)::key_type`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is quite explicit, `decltype(map)` is `const std::map<Args... >&`, which is  a `const`-reference to a `std::map`. Since it's a reference type, it does not have a `::key_type`.

You need to use `std::remove_reference_t` to drop the reference:

```
static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<
    typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(map)>::key_type,
    T 
>);
```

You need the `typename` because `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(map)>` is a dependent name.

A more idiomatic way would be to use a `Map` template parameter and not constrain the function to `std::map`:

```
template<typename T, typename Map>
inline bool contains(const Map &map, const T& value) noexcept {
  static_assert(std::is_constructible_v< typename Map::key_type , T >);
  return map.find(value) != std::end(map);
}
```

Comment: ok, I didn't know than reference type have no ::key_type (or value_type for other containers I suppose). Thank you.
The second approch seems interesting, but is in conflict with contains function that I have done for others containers (for example std::array doesn't have .find() method), so I choose to use explicit std::map in the function.

Comment: `std::is_constructible_v<typename std::map<Args...>::key_type, T>` works too (i.e. we already have the map type!) but your suggestion is better.

Comment: @Kafka You can disable such overload with some SFINAE by checking that the container `Map` indeed has a `::key_type`. You could also make a generic version with [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) but unfortunately there are no guarantees regarding the complexity of `std::find` on sets or maps...

Comment: @Kafka Here is a possible version with SFINAE and a small trait to check if a type is an associative container (`set` / `map` and their `unordered_` versions): https://godbolt.org/z/7uXSpU Not including this in the answer since it is a bit far from the question.

Answer (score 0):

The earlier answer explained the reason for the error, which does answer the question, but I wanted to expand on the solution to the problem:

---

Instead of converting the value back into its type to get the `key_type`, you can grab it from the type directly:

```
template <class T, class ... Args >
inline bool contains(const std::map<Args...>& map, const T& value) noexcept
{
    using Key = typename std::map<Args...>::key_type;

    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<Key, T>);

    return map.find(value) != std::end(map);
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jqGvq1Ke5) (Note that the code in the question uses `C++17` syntax, despite the `C++11` tag)

---

But I think a better solution is to name the appropriate template type:

```
template <class T, class Key, class ... Args >
inline bool contains(const std::map<Key, Args...>& map, const T& value) noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<Key, T>);

    return map.find(value) != std::end(map);
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oxM951qfj)